Constructing closed sets as union of open sets in topology
I just started learning topology as a part of functional analysis in undergrad and I have a small problem - I probably don't understand the three constructing axioms of topology correctly (construction via open sets).
I understand that a topology should be closed under any union, even countably-infinite one, which can be written as
$(\forall\alpha\in A, G_\alpha\in\tau)\implies\cup_{\alpha\in A}\;G_\alpha\in\tau$,
Where $A$ is an index set and $\tau$ is said topology. But what if I do the union
$\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\;(a +\frac{1}{n}, b) = [a, b)$?
That is a union of countably infinitely many open sets (under standard Euclidean topology), but the result is the half-open interval [a, b), which is not open under standard Euxlidean topology, as I understand it. Where is the error in my thinking?
Thanks for your answer : ).

You haven't computed the union correctly:
$$
    \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty (a + 1 / n, b) = (a, b)
$$
which is open. In particular, $a$ isn't contained in any interval of the form $(a + 1 / n, b)$ so it cannot be in the union.
